# PUT and POST Request of .save() of Backbonejs model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

How to be confirmed whether a backbonejs `.save()` is sending PUT request ?? I checked my server side, which is working good, there is no problem in server side. But my `.save()` is not working.

Here is my model of backbone

```
define(['underscore','backbone'],function(_,Backbone) 
{
    var my_model = Backbone.Model.extend(
    { 
        urlRoot: "http://localhost/back/server_file.php/number"
    });         
    return my_model;
});
```

Here is how I am using `.save()`

```
var my_data = {
            id: data.id, 
            code: data.code
        };   

        var My_model = new my_model();  

        My_model.save(my_data, 
        {
            success: function(response) 
            {
                alert('Yes');

            },
            error: function(response)
            {
                alert('No');
            }
        });
```

I think my `.save()` is sending POST request to server.

**UPDATE**

I think I could find out my problem. I am describing that here.

***What I would like to do***

I would like to send 2 parameters from backbonejs model to server side script (I am using PHP SLIM Framework). Based on those 2 parameters server side script update a record's(2 field of this record match with those 2 parameters ) another field with a static parameter at database.

***What backbonejs provide*** (As I think )

Backbonejs has a model with id as JSON format. Backbonejs sends PUT request to server side script. Server side script just dump (update) the data(which was as JSON format,like a bundle) to the database with matching id. Serer side script would not like to look inside the data.

I am getting (from network tab of firebug) my PUT request URL is like   `http://localhost/back/server_file.php/number/1 (This is the id)` . On the other hand I would like to get URL is like   `http://localhost/back/server_file.php/number/1 (id the first parameter)/456 (Second parameter)`.

If I am right, anyone could say how can I implement my plan??

Comment: See in `network` tab of Chrome Developer Tools or you can use a network tool like `Fiddler` to see all requests.

Comment: Thanks @coding_idiot for your reply.

I got URL from network panel is **http://localhost/back/server_file.php/number/1**

Where is the problem??

Comment: It depends if the model already exists on the server (i.e. the model has an id attribute). If it already exists, **PUT** is used by the underlying `Backbone.sync` method. If the model doesn't exist on server (no id attribute), **POST** is used. See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save.

Comment: Thanks @kandilaki for your reply. You could understand my point. Actually I know your words but how can I implement that in my code ??

Comment: I think your question is not exactly about what you ultimately looking for. But if I understood you right, you'd like the `save` method to use PUT instead of POST. Well, if that's the case, then you could define the request type to be used by the underlying Backbone.sync: `model.save(data, {type: 'PUT', success: function...})`

Comment: Thanks @kandilaki.  
I am trying like this  

           `My_model.save(user_data, 
            {
                type:'PUT',
                success: function(response) 
                {                   
                    alert('Yes');                    
                },
                error: function(response)
                {                  
                    alert('No');
                }
            });`  



But this is not working.

Comment: @kandilaki ,should I retrieve a record from database to update a record of database using `.save()` of backbonejs model ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
My_model.set(my_data);

My_model.save(null, {
  wait : true,
  url : "http://localhost/back/server_file.php/number/1/456",
  success : function(response){
  },
  error : function(e){
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the request being sent in `network` tab of `Chrome Developer Tools` or you can use a network tool like `Fiddler` to see all requests.

Refer the attached on where to see the request method being used.

[image]